# Fixed point of unusual integral equation

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, fixed-point-theorems, integral-equations

I am a little rusty in this area so please forgive the slowness. I am trying to prove or disprove the existence of fixed points for the following integral equation. Throughout I am interested in the metric space $C[0,1]$ which is complete under the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ norm.

Define $\Phi: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1] $ by

$$\Phi(x)(\theta)  = \frac{c(\theta)   } {c(\theta) + N \int_0^1 x(t) c(t) dt    }. $$ Surely some restrictions on $c(\theta)$ will be needed, but I would rather make them as loose as possible. If it helps, for concreteness put $c(t) = t + t^p$. $N$ and $p$ are known positive parameters.

I am trying to show a solution to the  equation $\Phi(x) = x$ exists. I tried to show $\Phi$ is a contraction mapping without success. Moreover, for the particular $c(\cdot)$ above I can see that $\Vert \Phi(\mathbf{1}) - \Phi(\mathbf{0})\Vert = \Vert \mathbf{1} - \mathbf{0} \Vert = 1. $ Is this a correct counterexample to $\Phi$ being a contraction mapping?

If so, do I have much hope of showing existence? I was hoping there was a clean fixed-point theorem I could quote, but I haven't found any so far.

Comment: I think this is confused.  $\Phi(x)(\theta)$ is a function of $x$ and $\theta$ which is well defined for a given $c(\theta)$ by your equation.  $x$ is not a function of $t$, which would allow it to be pulled out of the integral.  To show that $\Phi(x)(\theta)=x$ is a solution for a specific $c(\theta)$ you would just have to plug it into the equation.  The contraction mapping theorem would apply if you somehow plugged $\Phi$ into the right and iterated to convergence.  You would have to define a metric on the space $\Phi$ is in to show that the iteration is a contraction.

Comment: Perhaps the extra (typo) 'exists' was confusing. I have removed it. But I don't see what you mean by '$x$ is not a function of $t$'. $x$ is some continuous function on [0,1] and $t$ just a dummy variable of integration. It can't be pulled out of the integral.
The solution isn't $\Phi(x)(\theta)$, the solution would be a function $x(\theta)$ that solves the functional equation $\Phi(x) = x$. That is, it would solve $\Phi(x)(\theta) = x(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in [0,1].$ 
Or perhaps I am indeed very confused. Please let me know if this clears it up.